# How many perfect squares can be displayed on a 12-digit calculator?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The question is:  "How many perfect squares can be displayed on a 12-digit calculator?"

According to my "solution" book, the answer is 999,999. I have no idea how that happened!

Answer (score 2):

The largest number will be $10^{12} - 1$.

Largest square  will be $10^6 - 1$.

Thus the number of perfect squares will be $10^6 - 1$